# Asymptotic expansion of $\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{ne^{-\sqrt{t}}}{1+n^2t^2}\,dt$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, asymptotics

I would like to get a general formula to get the asymptotic expansion at the order $n$ (so at whatever precision I want) of the following integral :

$$I = \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{ne^{-\sqrt{t}}}{1+n^2t^2} \mathrm{d}t$$

Some thoughts :

For now I am able to find an asymptotic expansion of order $1$. First intuitively we have :

$$I = O \left ( \frac{1}{n} \right )$$

From the expression :
$$\frac{ne^{-\sqrt{t}}}{1+n^2t^2}$$

The change of variable : $\tan(\theta) = nt$ suggests itself and the problem boils down to calculating an asymptotic expansion of :

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} e^{-\sqrt{\frac{\tan(\theta)}{n}}} \mathrm{d}\theta$$

Now it is possible to use the dominated convergence theorem because we have :

$$e^{-\sqrt{\frac{\tan(\theta)}{n}}} \leq 1$$

Yet there is still a problem since $I$ is an improper and integral, so by using the dominated convergence theorem we only get an asymptotic expansion and not the exact value.

That’s why I get the following asymptotic (of order $1$):

$$\frac{\pi}{2} + O \left ( \frac{1}{n} \right )$$

Now is it possible to expand this in order to get a general formula for the asymptotic expansion of $I$ at whatever order we want ?

Comment: Missed a $dt$ out of the first integral

Comment: @Henry Lee, thank you for noticing it !

Comment: Just out of curiosity : may I ask in which context you faced this problem ? A former student of mine had it in statistical thermodynamics. As I wrote, if you want many terms, just tell me. Cheers.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici Actually a friend of mine got this exercise during a math exam (the question was simpler as it was just asking for the first two terms of the asymptotic expansion). Yet this is actually quite interesting if this function has a link with physics. For now I am ok with the asymptotic expansion, I think that now I have a good feeling of how it behave. Thank you ! I am just disappointed that the substitution I made doesn’t seem to help much since I can only get one term of the asymptotic expansion.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Changing $u=z^2/n$ and $\zeta=n^{-1/2}$, the integral can be expressed as
\begin{align}
 I(\zeta) &= \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{ne^{-\sqrt{t}}}{1+n^2t^2} \,dt\\
 &=\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{2u}{1+u^4}e^{-\zeta u}\,du
\end{align}
We use the Mellin transform method for Laplace transforms with small parameters ([DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/2.5.iii)). Here,
\begin{align}
 h(u)&=\frac{2u}{1+u^4}\\
 &\sim 2\sum_{s=0}^\infty (-1)^s u^{-3-4s}
\end{align}
for $u\to\infty$ and $h(u)=O\left( u \right)$ for $u\to 0$. The Mellin transform
\begin{equation}
 \mathfrak M\left[ h(u)\right](z)=\frac{\pi}{2\sin\left( \frac{\pi}{4}(z+1) \right)}
\end{equation} 
for $-1<z<3$. The asymptotic expansion can then  be expressed as
\begin{equation}
 I(\zeta)= \mathfrak M\left[ h(u)\right](1)+\sum_{k=2}^l \operatorname{Res}\left[-\zeta^{z-1}\Gamma(1-z)\frac{\pi}{2\sin\left( \frac{\pi}{4}(z+1) \right)};z=k \right]+O\left( \zeta^{l-\delta-1} \right)
\end{equation} 
for $l>2$ and $\delta$ is a arbitrary small positive constant. Here $\psi(z)=\Gamma'(z)/\Gamma(z)$. We find, the values of the residues $R_k$ 
\begin{align}
R_k&=\frac{2(-1)^{\frac{k+1}{4}}\zeta^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}\left[ \ln \zeta-\psi(k-2)-\frac{2k-3}{(k-1)(k-2)}\right]\text{ for } k= 3+4p \qquad (p=0,1,2\ldots)\\
 &=\frac{(-1)^{k-1}\pi\zeta^{k-1}}{2(k-1)!\sin\left( \frac{\pi}{4}(k+1) \right)}\text{ for } k\ge 2 \text{ and } k\ne 3+4p\qquad (p=0,1,2\ldots)
\end{align} 
By keeping the first terms ($k=2,3$) one obtains
\begin{equation}
 I\sim\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2n} }-\frac{1}{n}\left[ \ln \zeta+\gamma-\frac{3}{2}\right]
\end{equation}

Comment: Similar answer with Mathematica: `AsymptoticIntegrate[(n*Exp[-Sqrt[t]])/(
   1 + n^2*t^2), {t, 0, Infinity}, {n, Infinity, 1}] // 
  FullSimplify // Expand` so:$-\frac{\gamma }{n}+\frac{3}{2 n}-\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{n}}+\frac{\log (n)}{2 n}+\frac{\pi }{2}$

Comment: Thanks for the check @MariuszIwaniuk

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ! Unfortunately I don’t know the Mellin transform yet. I am going to read on this tonight and accept your answer tomorrow so that I can understand it :) Hope you don’t mind.

Comment: You are welcome. Thanks for the question.

Answer (score 8):

What's about good old asymptotic matching? This is at least feasible to get the first two (or maybe three,four,... terms if you are bit more patient)  of the expansion, without the need to have heavy artillery from complex analysis at hand.

Let us first fix a constant $\Delta<<1$  depending on $n$ such that $\Delta n \rightarrow
\infty $ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. The exact size depends on the order of matching and can be specified in the end so that the Expansion is consistent ($1/n^{\delta},\,\,1>\delta>0$ will suit our needs)
Let us write ($J=I/n$)

> $$
> J=J_1+J_2=\int_0^{\Delta}f_n(x)dx+\int_{\Delta}^{\infty}f_n(x)dx
> $$

where $f_n(x):=\frac{e^{-\sqrt{x}}}{1+n^2 x^2}$.

---

Let  us start with the Analysis of $J_1$

In the interval $[0,\Delta]$ we can expand the exponential as a Taylor series since $x<<1$:

$$
J_1\sim\int_0^{\Delta}\frac{\color{\red}{1}-\color{\green}{\sqrt{x}}+\color{\orange}{O(x)}}{1+n^2 x^2}dx
$$

Integrating termwise yields

$$
J_1\sim\color{\red}{\frac{\arctan(\Delta n)}{n}}+\color{\green}{\frac{e^{i\pi/4}(\arctan(e^{i\pi/4}\sqrt{\Delta n})-\text{arctanh}(e^{i\pi/4}\sqrt{\Delta n}))}{n^{3/2}}}+\color{\orange}{O(\log(\Delta n)/n^2)}
$$

Expanding up to $O(\sqrt{\Delta} n^{2})^{-1}$ we get (discarding small terms)
$$
J_1\sim\color{\red}{\frac{\pi}{2 n}-\frac{1}{\Delta n^2}}-\color{\green}{\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}n^{3/2}}+2\frac{1}{n^2\sqrt{\Delta}}}+\color{\orange}{O(\log(n)n^{-2})}
$$

---

Now, let's consider $J_2$

For $J_2$ we can Taylor the fraction around infinity since $xn>>1$ on $[\Delta,\infty]$

$$
J_2\sim\frac{1}{n^2}\int_{\Delta}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\sqrt{x}}}{x^2}\left(\color{\purple}{1}+O((nx)^{-2})\right)
$$

Integrating by parts twice we get

$$
J_2\sim\color{\purple}{\frac{e^{-\sqrt{\Delta}}}{\Delta n^2}-\frac{e^{-\sqrt{\Delta}}}{\sqrt{\Delta} n^2}}
$$

Expanding up to $O(\sqrt{\Delta} n^{2})^{-1}$ yields (discarding small terms)
$$
J_2\sim\color{\purple}{\frac{1}{\Delta n^2}-2\frac{1}{n^2\sqrt{\Delta}}}
$$

---

Adding both integrals, we see that the parts containing $\Delta$ exactly cancel which makes our Expansion consistent up to the order in question, and we can state our final result

> $$
> I=nJ=n(J_1+J_2)\sim \color{\red}{\frac{\pi}{2 }}-\color{\green}{\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}n^{1/2}} }+\color{\orange}{O(\log(n)n^{-1})}
> $$

PS:Thanks for the idiotic downvote

Comment: Thank you ! This is really interesting and more understandable for me since I don’t know much about complex analysis. What is interesting is the way you cut the integral so that you can use Taylor series on every parts of $f_n$. Nevertheless I am a bit surprised that no one used the substitution $ t = \tan(\theta)$ (the one that I made in my post), since it seems to simplify a lot the function, yet using this form I am having a hard time even finding the second term of the asymptotic expansion. Do you have any thoughts on that ? Thank you. P.S: I don’t know who downvotes you. (+1)

Answer (score 4):

*Using a CAS.*
$$I = \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{ne^{-\sqrt{t}}}{1+n^2t^2} \,dt=\frac{64 \sqrt{2} }{\pi ^{3/2}}n^2\, G_{1,5}^{5,1}\left(\frac{1}{256 n^2}|
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{3}{2} \\
 1,\frac{5}{4},\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2},\frac{7}{4}
\end{array}
\right)$$ where appears the Meijer G function.

Expanding for large values of $n$
$$I=\frac{\pi }{2}-\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{2}\,n^{1/2}}+\frac{\log
   \left({n}\right)-2 \gamma +3}{2\, n}+\frac{\pi 
  }{6 \sqrt{2}\,n^{3/2}}-\frac{\pi }{48\,
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{5/2}}\right)$$ For $n=10$, the "exact" result would be $\approx 1.086826$ while the above gives $\approx 1.086776$.

No problem to get more terms (if you want).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I dind’t know about the Meijer G function.